# Angular route with segment variables not reloading the child component when the url changes dynamically

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-animations

Angular route with segment variables not reloading the child component when the url changes dynamically.

I am trying to have both the parentRoute and the childRoute inside one component and whenver i click on the one of the parent button i want  the child component to reload.

More on that on the simple example:

// Read this after you went  through the example

The thing that i noticed is that when the url changes i.e buttons is clicked //this.router.navigate([`/years/`, year]);, the child component only loads once(for the first time) And then after it while clicking on other button the child component is not getting realoded.

Also, the component is only loaded when the value(object in this case is getting reinitialized). Even if that is partialliy what i want to make a request and then get new data, i also want to trigger some animation on the route change on the parent level which means TO REALOAD MY CHILD COMPONENT in this case.

Is there any other way to achieve this:

What i tried until now:

- this.router.navigate([`/years/`, year], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
- Adding a resolver for  the child compoennt and then get the data while subscribing to the activated route.
- this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false; but it is causing some wierd behaviour on my application

```
**// ROUTES**
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'years',
    title: "Years",
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [{
      path: ':year', component: ChildComponent
    }],
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'years', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

```
**// App component HTML**
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
**// Parent component html**
<h1>2022</h1>
<button   mat-button *ngFor="let year of years" (click)="createYear(year)">{{year}}</button>
  <main #main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
    <router-outlet
      #outlet="outlet">
    </router-outlet>
  </main>
```

```
**// Parent component TS**
  //Animation 
  export const slider = trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition('* => isLeft', slideTo('left')),
  transition('* => isRight', slideTo('right')),
  transition('isRight => *', slideTo('left')),
  transition('isLeft => *', slideTo('right')),
])

function slideTo(direction: string) {
  const optional = {optional: true};
  return [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'relative',
        top: '10px',
        [direction]: 0,
        width: '100%',

      })
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      style({[direction]: '-100%'})
    ], {optional: true}),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({[direction]: '100%'}))
      ], optional),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({[direction]: '0%'}))
      ], optional),
    ])
  ];
}


  
  public years = [
    2021,
    2022,
    2023,
    2024,
    2025,
    2026,
    2027,
    2028,
    2029,
    2030,
    2031,
  ]
   ...code 

public prepareRoute(routerOutlet: RouterOutlet) {
   **// HERE I WANT TO SLIDE THE CHILD ROUTE EITHER FROM RIGHT OR LEFT**
   return routerOutlet && routerOutlet.activatedRouteData  &&  'isLeft';

  }
  ...code

 createYear(year: any) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/years/${year}`);
    // this.router.navigate([`/years/`, year]);
  }
```

```
// CHILD Component
<p>child works!</p>
<p>{{ value.hello}}</p>
```

```
**// Child component TS**
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  private year: any;

  constructor(private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  public value = {hello: "world"}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.year = params['year'];
    })
    
    // Do the api request with year
    // httpClient.call(year)

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.value = {hello: "Second"}
    }, 4000)
    
    
    console.log("Child called")
  }

}
```

Comment: Not, it's not executed the "Init". If you want to do "anything", write the actions **inside** the subscribe function, `this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(..=>{..and do something..})`

Comment: Yes. But it is not causing the animation to change.

Comment: I imagine you can get it subscribing in main to [router.events](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#events) but it's difficult know with so few data in your question

Comment: @Eliseo i will edit the example above. Maybe it is not the best approch to use angular route animation for this specific use case but it was good experimenting at least.